# Broken user, broken Data.Binary or broken installation?

Tags: haskell, serialization

I'm trying to use **Data.Binary** to serialize a Map but I got an error: *not enough bytes*. I then tried to make an easier example work with a **list of integers**, here, that doesn't work either. What could possibly be wrong? Is there an error in my code, something I misunderstood or could there be a problem with my installation, and in that case how do I solve it?

Below is my test code...

```
import Data.Binary

worldfile = "binarysimple.world"
main = do
  ser <- decodeFileOrFail worldfile
  case ser of
       Right w -> showWorld $ show (w :: [Int]) 
       Left (_,s) -> putStrLn ("the error:"++s) >> newworld

newworld = do
  let world = [1,2,3] :: [Int]
  showWorld $ show world 
  encodeFile worldfile $ encode world

showWorld = putStrLn
```

... and the output when running it:

```
ghci binarysimple.hs
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( binarysimple.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> main
Loading package array-0.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package containers-0.5.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.10.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package binary-0.7.1.0 ... linking ... done.
the error:demandInput: not enough bytes
[1,2,3]
*Main> newworld
[1,2,3]
*Main> main
the error:demandInput: not enough bytes
[1,2,3]
*Main> newworld
[1,2,3]
*Main>
Leaving GHCi.
$ ls -l binarysimple.world
-rw-r--r--  1 btobias  staff  40  8 Sep 21:15 binarysimple.world
```

I don't know about the exact format, but this could be reasonable output:

```
$ hexdump -C binarysimple.world
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03  |....... ........|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03                           |........|
00000028
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The Problem

Let's review what you think you're doing and what you are doing.

You think you are using `binary` to encode a list of `Int`s and write that bytestring into a file.  Then, you read from the file and decode a list of `Int`s only to have it fail.

What you are actually doing is encoding a list of `Int`s as a bytestring then encoding that bytestring as a bytestring (so, an extra length field is prepended to the bytes) and writing that bytestring to disk.  Your decode then fails because you have on disk `encode(encode(list))` instead of `encode(list)`.

## The solution

Just change the line reading:

```
encodeFile worldfile $ encode world
```

to

```
encodeFile worldfile world
```

## Reading Hexdump

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03  |....... ........|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03
```

So the above hexdump can be read as a series of 64 bit integers: 0x20, 3, 1, 2, 3.  The first value, decimal 32, is part of the encoding of `Bytestring` and indicates the length of the remaining bytestring (8 bytes * 4 ints).  The second value, 3, is part of the encoding of lists - it indicates the length of the list.  The final values are the individual elements of the list.

Finally, you don't need some random person online to explain the format to you, you can just read the format from the instances in the `binary` package (once you are familiar enough with Haskell).